# Is the quotient map $X\to X/G$ a covering map?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $G$ be a group acting on a topological space $X$. Suppose that every $x,x' \in X$ that are not in the same orbit of the $G$-action have open neighborhood $U$ and $U'$ such tath $g(U)\cap U'=\phi$ for all $g\in G$.

$a)$. Show that $X/G$ is a Hausdorff space.
$b)$. Is the quotient map $X\to X/G$ a covering map?

I just know the definitions and I have been just learning algebraic topology.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Think about this : Let $\lambda>1$ be real. Let $\mathbb{Z}$ act on $\mathbb{R}^2-\{\vec{0}\}$ by letting $1$ act as the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\lambda}\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @CharlieFrohman: This is indeed a good example but for a different question. In this question points $x, x'$ are in different orbits.

Comment: I am not able to visualize with this sort of information. Can someone help me a little more?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the action of the additive group of real numbers on itself via translations.

Answer (score 0):

Same question posted here, but I too am struggling with all "hints" given:
[When is Quotient Map a Covering Map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542222/when-is-quotient-map-a-covering-map)

Specifically, for b) it seems like we want that any points which lie in the same orbit must lie in disjoint open sets from each other. But I don't think we have that from the given condition? That is, I think we would want g(U) intersect U to be empty for all non-identity g. Or can we use the fact that the projection map is open somehow?

Some of the hints it's unclear to me whether even they are suggesting an approach to a), or a counterexample to b).....

Comment: We have to use that fact that projection map(quotient map) is open otherwise we can not prove the map is a covering.